# Scaling / Normalizing pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe like:

```
TOTAL | Name
3232     Jane
382      Jack
8291     Jones
```

I'd like to create a newly scaled column in the dataframe called `SIZE` where `SIZE` is a number between 5 and 50.

For Example:

```
TOTAL | Name | SIZE
3232     Jane   24.413
382      Jack   10
8291     Jones  50
```

I've tried

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd

scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(10,50))
df["SIZE"]=scaler.fit_transform(df["TOTAL"])
```

but got `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

I've tried other things, such as creating a list, transforming it, and appending it back to the dataframe, among other things.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: why 8291 is 40 should it be 50  ?

Comment: the numbers themselves are inconsequential, Primarily, I need a way to scale data from a column onto a new column in a dataframe

Comment: 8291 is the max among 3  so should it be 50 rather than 40 ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Option 1**
`sklearn`
You see this problem time and time again, the error really should be indicative of what you need to do. You're basically missing a superfluous dimension on the input. Change `df["TOTAL"]` to `df[["TOTAL"]]`.

```
df['SIZE'] = scaler.fit_transform(df[["TOTAL"]])
```

```
df
   TOTAL   Name       SIZE
0   3232   Jane  24.413959
1    382   Jack  10.000000
2   8291  Jones  50.000000
```

---

**Option 2**
`pandas`
Preferably, I would bypass sklearn and just do the min-max scaling myself.

```
a, b = 10, 50
x, y = df.TOTAL.min(), df.TOTAL.max()
df['SIZE'] = (df.TOTAL - x) / (y - x) * (b - a) + a
```

```
df
   TOTAL   Name       SIZE
0   3232   Jane  24.413959
1    382   Jack  10.000000
2   8291  Jones  50.000000
```

This is essentially what the min-max scaler does, but without the overhead of importing scikit learn (don't do it unless you have to, it's a heavy library).

Comment: That is why I asking him twice about the out put ...it should be 50 ...

Comment: @Wen their output was created with the assumption that there was some more data which is not shown. In this isolated case with 3 rows, the last value should be 50. However, since OP presumably has more than 3 rows, some other value is larger, and that value will become 50.

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to scale only one column in the dataframe, you have to reshape the column values as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df['SIZE'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['TOTAL'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use this function several times, you can use it to normalize your dataset

```
def standardize_function(X_train):

    df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X_train), columns = X_train.columns)

    return df_scaled

X_train = standardize_function(X_train)
```

You can try it out and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minmax_scale` to normalize a column

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
df['size'] = minmax_scale(df['total'])
```