# Scaling pandas column to be between specified min and max numbers

Tags: python, pandas, scale

Let us say, I have the following data frame.

```
Frequency  
20
14
10
8
6
2
1
```

I want to scale `Frequency` value from 0 to 1.

Is there a way to do this in Python? I have found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027959/scaling-normalizing-pandas-column) But it doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: Any random scaling from 0 to 1 based on their number of Frequency. The highest frequency has highest value in the scaling as well.

Comment: in the question linked, the accepted answer has 2 options they should work if you have a data frame. what do you mean by doesn't serve your purpose?

Comment: The linked answer doesn't scale from 0 to 1. That is my point.

Comment: @jezrael Can you write it in the answer properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `a, b = 10, 50` to `a, b = 0, 1` in [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50028155/2901002) for upper and lower values for scale:

```
a, b = 0, 1
x, y = df.Frequency.min(), df.Frequency.max()
df['normal'] = (df.Frequency - x) / (y - x) * (b - a) + a
print (df)
   Frequency    normal
0         20  1.000000
1         14  0.684211
2         10  0.473684
3          8  0.368421
4          6  0.263158
5          2  0.052632
6          1  0.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there's a more standard way to do this in Python, but I use a self-defined function that you can select the range to be scaled on:

```
def my_scaler(min_scale_num,max_scale_num,var):
    return (max_scale_num - min_scale_num) * ( (var - min(var)) / (max(var) - min(var)) ) + min_scale_num

# You can input your range
df['scaled'] = my_scaler(0,1,df['Frequency'].astype(float)) # scaled between 0,1
df['scaled2'] = my_scaler(-5,5,df['Frequency'].astype(float)) # scaled between -5,5
```

---

```
df

   Frequency    scaled   scaled2
0         20  1.000000  5.000000
1         14  0.684211  1.842105
2         10  0.473684 -0.263158
3          8  0.368421 -1.315789
4          6  0.263158 -2.368421
5          2  0.052632 -4.473684
6          1  0.000000 -5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `applymap` to apply any function on each cell of the df.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([20, 14, 10, 8, 6, 2, 1], columns=["Frequency"])
min = df.min()
max = df.max()
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: (x - min)/(max-min))

df
   Frequency
0         20
1         14
2         10
3          8
4          6
5          2
6          1

df2
0       Frequency    1.0
dtype: float64
1  Frequency    0.684211
dtype: float64
2  Frequency    0.473684
dtype: float64
3  Frequency    0.368421
dtype: float64
4  Frequency    0.263158
dtype: float64
5  Frequency    0.052632
dtype: float64
6       Frequency    0.0
dtype: float64
```