# Pandas how to bin and groupby without categorical range of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, vaex

I have a large number of latitude and longitude values that I would like to bin together in order to display them on a heatmap (`ipyleaflet` only seems to allow 2000 or so points in the heatmap and this would also be much more efficient when using big data).

I am actually using `vaex`, but a answer in terms of `pandas` is also fine.

The `pandas` `pd.cut` function seems to be helpful in terms of binning, however it produces a categorical column (`category` `dtype`) which looks like a list of all the values in the bin. Is there some way of changing this to just be an incremental number identifying each bin (thanks jezreal for that part of the answer)? I just need a bin number in order to then `groupby` the bin number and average (`mean`) on the latitude and longitude columns. I also need a count for the intensity of the heatmap entry.

For example:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({
    'latitude': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'longitude': [3, 0.2, 2, 0.2, 1.1]
    })

dft['bin'] = pd.cut(dft['latitude'], bins=3, labels=False).astype(str) + "_" + pd.cut(dft['longitude'], bins=3, labels=False).astype(str)

dft.groupby('bin').agg(['mean', 'count']).unstack()

Almost gives me the answer, but I think I want this output instead:

bin latitude_mean longitude_mean count
0_0 0.7           0.2            2
0_1 1.2           2.0            1
1_2 1.5           3.0            1
2_0 3.0           1.1            1
```

It would be helpful if the count can be normalized between 1 and 1000.

How can I use `pandas` `pd.cut` or something else to `groupby` the bin in the rows, average on the latitude and longitude and (heatmap intensity) count in the columns?

Comment: What means `intensity count` ? Is possible add some small data sample and see expected output?

Comment: `intensity count` is the count of the number of the values in the bin which would then be used as a heatmap intensity. The value should be normalized between 1 and 1000.

Comment: Super, thank you. So finally after normalize how looks ouput?

Comment: I guess the normalization should happen as an additional step, whereby it takes the maximum count and then scale the counts so that 1000 becomes the new maximum and the other values interpolate as integers inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pandas pd.cut function seems to be helpful in terms of binning, however it produces a categorical column (category dtype) which looks like a list of all the values in the bin. Is there some way of changing this to just be an incremental number identifying each bin

Yes, use `label=False` parameter in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> labels array or False, default None
> Specifies the labels for the returned bins. Must be the same length as the resulting bins. If False, returns only integer indicators of the bins.

Last use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for aggregation and last normalize `count` column:

```
df = dft.groupby('bin').agg(latitude_mean=('latitude','mean'),
                            longitude_mean=('longitude','mean'),
                            count=('latitude','count'))

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/50028155/2901002
a, b = 1, 1000
x, y = df['count'].min(),df['count'].max()
df['count'] = (df['count'] - x) / (y - x) * (b - a) + a

print (df)

     latitude_mean  longitude_mean   count
bin                                       
0_0            0.7             0.2  1000.0
0_1            1.2             2.0     1.0
1_2            1.5             3.0     1.0
2_0            3.0             1.1     1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part of the answer, I have changed my question to hopefully be more clear about my needs and to provide an example.

Comment: @Superdooperhero - Answer was edited. (btw cool nick ;))

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was useful in many ways!